# Windows: migration among the domains

Tags: windows, active-directory, migration

I got a LAN with 5 computers on Windows(Server 2008 and XP) which work on other domain. And I got Domain Controller with Active Directory on it. How can I move my LAN into my Active Directory Domain?

Answer (score 1):

Are those computers already joined to a domain and you're looking for a way to move them to a new one, or are they currently in workgroup mode and you want them to become members of a domain? Also, is the domain controller on the same network or on a different one?

Either way, moving them to the domain is quite easy: just ensure they can communicate with the domain controller, configure them use your domain controller as their DNS server and modify the system properties to make them members of the domain.

What can be tricky is moving existing users and user data... but we need more information to answer about this.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that Windows operating systems are not the home versions as they are not able to join a domain.  If the workstations are already part of another domain, then the workstations are capable of recognizing multiple domains.  From a windows XP Pro machine, right click my computer, select properties, select the Computer Name tab, and click the Network ID button to get started on a Wizzard that will guide you through adding it to a domain.  This is under the assumption that network/firewall settings are such that kerberos/ldap can communicate between server and client computers.